# How to replace single qoute to backslash+single qoute in Python

Tags: python, regex, replace

Need to replace `'` to `\'`
But that what I get:

```
>>> s = "It's nice to have an example"
>>> s.replace("'", "\\'")
"It\\'s nice to have an example"
>>> s.replace("'", "\'")
"It's nice to have an example"
>>> s.replace("'", "\\\'")
"It\\'s nice to have an example"
```

How to get `"It\'s nice to have an example"` result?

Comment: You've got it right. Python is escaping the `\` again when it displays it, but the string itself is correct. Try `print`ing the value, and you'll see it correctly.

Comment: If you want to see how a string looks like *when printed*... why don't you *print* it? Note that the interactive interpreter does *not* print the string, it shows its string representation (i.e. it does the equivalent of `print(repr(text))`, note the extra `repr`).

Comment: I just need to escape the single qoute and I want to get single backslash in repr. Cause when I serialize that I got in my javascript code: `SmObj.initialize('[{"description": "My belgian sheepdog! Isn\\'t she cute?", "author": {"username": "Marabesta", "get_full_name": "Olga Smith"}, {...}, ...]');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already got it right, but the `repr`esentation of the string threw you off. Try:

```
print s.replace("'", "\\'")
=>  It\'s nice to have an example
```

If you don't use `print`, the `repr` of the resulting string is displayed (and not its `str`), and in this `repr`, backslashes are escaped, resulting with double-backslash.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr-in-python), about `__str__` and `__repr__`.

---

**EDIT** -- since you mentioned in a comment that you need a string you can use in javascript...

Use [json.dumps()](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/json.html), instead of `repr`.

Comment: But how can I get one backslah in `repr`?

Comment: what do you need it for? `print` is what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can use `encode` with `string-escape` encoding:

```
>>> s = "It's nice to have an example"
>>> s = s.encode('string-escape')
>>> print s
It\'s nice to have an example
```